# Stretching the div to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently making my site,

http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats&id=12&action=all

The white div seems to only go to the bottom of the page when there is a whole pages of content on the page. When there isn't enough content on the page it don't go all the way down to the bottom shown here:

http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=status

How would I go about making it so whatever is on the page the white div always goes to the bottom of the page here my CSS:

```
.whitebg 
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -625;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1250px;
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try `min-height` in combination with `height: 100%`, but that isn't going to push your footer to the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 0):

set the height of the html and the body to 100%, then set the white div to min-height 100%

Answer (score 0):

The white div doesn't go to the bottom with `height: 100%` because the parent div's of `.whitebg` aren't set to `height: 100%`. So what do you have to do is to set the height of all parent's div of `.whitebg` to `height: 100%;`

I just made a simple example:

Here, the white div doesn't go to the bottom of the page:
http://jsfiddle.net/sntjcark

And here we go, it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/sntjcark/1/

I just added `height: 100%` to both the html and the body tag.

Comment: http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=item&id=148

I've done that and now its giving me a bit of overflow and giving me a unnecessary scroll bar how would i remove that?

Comment: You got a lot of `<br>` in your code. I think these are causing the overflow. Try to remove them and try to set footer to the bottom with CSS (e.g. `bottom: 0`)

Comment: ive taken them out done that to the footer and its still doing this: http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats Do you think its a issue that the div isnt containing the navbar also?

Comment: The overflow is now causing by `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` and `margin-top` of `.whitebg`. So set `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` and `margin-top` to `0`. After that, wrap the content of `.whitebg` into a new div-element and set `padding-top: 60px` (for navbar) at the new-created div element.

**Careful:** For responsive design you have to change some CSS at screen size < 980px

Comment: Still making the scroll bar for some mad reason when i take away the height 100% it just makes it not the full way down.

Comment: I did it in the Chrome Debugger like I described and it worked... I will make an example later that day or tomorrow...